# Regular expressions in a shell

Tags: regular-expression

I have two questions about using regular expressions inside a shell.

### 1. Use of *

According to [wikipedia page on regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

> *: The asterisk indicates there is zero or more of the preceding element. For example, ab*c matches "ac", "abc", "abbc", "abbbc", and
>   so on.

However, when I write `rm test*.iso`, it will delete all files beginning by "test" and finishing by ".iso" whatever there is (or not) between "test" and ".iso". So, the file "tes.iso" will be *not* deleted.

If you take the abc example, according to wikipedia, "ab*c" matches "ac". Therefore `rm ab*c` should delete an "ac" file. **Why rm does not use regular expression as wikipedia describes them?**

### 2. Use of - and ?

Still according to [wikipedia page on regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

> ?: The question mark indicates there is zero or one of the preceding
>   element. For example, colou?r matches both "color" and "colour".
>
> +: The plus sign indicates there is one or more of the preceding element. For example, ab+c matches "abc", "abbc", "abbbc", and so on,
>   but not "ac".

"?" seems to work like "*", that is to say "?" symbol replaces one or zero element (but not the preceding one contrary as what wikipedia says).

I don't know how to use "+" and this is my second question. I'm also interested by any tricks concerning regular expressions and `rm, cp, ...`.

Comment: This question is **not** about `rm` using regular expressions (`rm` doesn't know anything about regexes). It is about the shell's pathname expansion and regexes. What makes you believe that the shell treats `whatever*` as an regex?

Comment: I reformulated my question. I hope it's correct now.

Comment: It seems you don't get it. The shell does not consider such code as regex at all. Thus it doesn't matter what you have read about regexes. The question is: How to make the shell use regex instead of plain globbing?

Comment: @HaukeLaging You said that the shell does not consider such code as regex but the shell do use * (for example) as tool for manipulating files.* means "whatever"; so * *is* a regular expression in a shell.

Comment: I did not downvote but in general, you should not ask multiple questions in a single post. Please break them up into separate questions.

Comment: @ppr "so * is a regular expression in a shell" No, that is plain wrong. There is a certain meaning of the term "regular expression" and the behaviour you point out does **not** fit this description. You cannot act like "Oh, there is something. I will refer to it as 'regular expression'." That does not make any sense at all. The shell uses `*` but that has nothing to do with regular expressions. It is called globbing.

Comment: @HaukeLaging On the content, you're wrong. A regular expression is "a sequence of characters that forms a search pattern, mainly for use in pattern matching with strings, or string matching" (wikipedia). So * in a shell is a regex (in a broad sense) even if the effect is a little different than * the common/most popular regex. * is not treated as plain text by the shell... I have also some remarks on the form of your comment, but this is not the place, so I created a [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14450/discussion-between-ppr-and-hauke-laging) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell's **pattern matching notation** is described in [this standards document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13).

As the document says in its introduction, pattern matching notation is related to, but slightly different from, regular expression notation.

In particular, `?` in the shell acts like `.` in a regular expression, and `*` in the shell acts like `.*` in a regular expression. (But neither of them will match a `.` at the beginning of a filename.) `+` in the shell does not have any special pattern-matching ability. However, as @HaukeLaging says in his answer, certain shells can optionally have regular expression notation enabled, although doing so is nonstandard.

Answer (score 0):

The shell uses regexes under certain conditions only (which probably differ from shell to shell).

In `bash` you have to activate them with: `shopt -s extglob`

After that you can use something like:

```
echo a*(b)c
```

See the block `Pattern Matching` in `man bash`.

Comment: That is not what I asked. I asked why regular expressions of the shell (available out of the box) doesn't work as regex. And Mark Plotnick answered well.

Comment: No. `@(ab*c)` is not regex. `@(...)` is used for alternation (like `@(foo|bar)`) in ksh regexp (a subset of which bash understands with the extglob option). The equivalent of regexp `ab*c` with ksh patterns is `a*(b)c`.

Comment: To get regexp with ksh patterns, it's `~(G:basic-regexp)`, `~(E:extended-regexp)`, `~(P:PCRE)` or `~(X:augmented-regexp)` (ksh93/ast specific). Those are not supported by bash or zsh though.